# circuitikz: error: cannot use all symbols

Tags: circuitikz

I cannot use all symbols for examble I want to use an thR resistor. In the old version of circuit there was no thR, but in Version 0.3.0 there is one. But I allways get an error when compiling. Somebody knows how to solve this problem?

Or must a special library for tikz loaded, if I use circuitikz

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) to [thR, o-o] (2,0)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Firstly, are you sure you're having the recent version that you claim has the command that you're looking forward to using? Why don't you post a MWE that'll illustrate what it is that you tried but could not get it to work...?

Comment: I updated Texlive, but I am not sure, if I have the latest version of circuitikz.

Comment: This compiles for me with a fairly recent TeXLive2012. You should add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}`, which will produce a list of the version numbers for the packages that were loaded.

Comment: circuitikz.sty    2009/11/18 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0.2
.4

ok, I have the old version. How to get the new version? I know it on windows, but now I have Linux mint cinnamon.

When I post "tex" in the Terminal it gives me:

Comment: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

back

Comment: @Latex_NOOB: What if you try `sudo apt-get install circuitikz`. I believe it should work in Mint as it's working on ubuntu.

Comment: Whenn I do this, it gives back: cannot find package

Comment: I found a solution:
I downloaded the package as zip from here:
https://github.com/mredaelli/circuitikz
I extracted it to usr/share/texmf and than tipped "texhash" in the terminal.

Thanks for every answer and help!